# Django API for Google Login

Tags: django, rest, google-api, django-allauth

I am going to implement Google Login using React+Django. I am using the package: `django-allauth` for social login(Google via API). When you enter `access_token` in GoogleLogin view, a user is registered in the database and `view` returns `key`. The same `key` for different `access_token`s. My question is, how can I use this `key` to extract data from database about this user. Can anyone help, please?